# Need a cron job that runs twice a day at random time

Tags: cron, redhat, rocky-os

I need to implement a cron job that runs twice a day at random time.

The objective is to deploy an rpm package containing the cron task but the cron task won't execute at the same time on deployed machines

I read a lot of similar problems on StackOverflow but none answered my question and i cznnot find an appropriate solution.

I do not want to use the sleep method because this would involve a sleep random(43200) and I think it's too much

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simple bash script that will generate two separate cron jobs for the first run and the second one.

Please change the `cmd` variable to your command of choice or script. (Note: If setting a script, make sure it is executable!)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the command you want to run
cmd="your_command_here"

# Generate random hour and minute for the first run
hour1=$((RANDOM % 24))
minute1=$((RANDOM % 60))

# Generate random hour and minute for the second run
hour2=$((RANDOM % 24))
minute2=$((RANDOM % 60))

# Create cronjobs for the two random times
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "$minute1 $hour1 * * * $cmd") | crontab -
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "$minute2 $hour2 * * * $cmd") | crontab -
```